# Is there a way to have navigation bar links only show up for people with specific access?

Tags: sharepoint-online, term-store, top-navigation

I was wondering if there way a way to add a new link to my navigation bar in SharePoint that only certain people with the right access can see.  I am aware that there are different groups with varying levels of permissions and my users are already put into those groups.  I was hoping to make an "Admin" option in the navbar that only shows up for a select few people with full access of the site.  Is there a way to accomplish what I want? I was thinking maybe in the Term Store Management tool but I didn't happen to see anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems audience targeting on navigational links will be the thing you want. The site owner must enable audience targeting for site navigation. Once enabled, any site editor can target menu links to specific audiences.

You can check it here:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-navigation-news-and-files-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293